# Unable to change width of a box in css - using extjs framework

Tags: css, extjs, element

I have tried below code in css:

```
.x-form-field {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    font: bold 22px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 10px;
    background: grey;
}
```

[Extjs tool bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Q5F.png)

And with this I am able to change, font, color, border and margins but not able to change the width of the box.

I want the default width to be `60 px;`

I have not worked on css before but i have been struggling with this for past 2 hours.  I might be overlooking something.Please help!

Comment: here is the code -

x-form-field{
width: 60px;
background: grey;
font: bold 22px Arial;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 10px;
border : red;
--margin-left :10px;
margin-right :10 px;
border: 10px solid red;
height: 200px;
width: 50%;
}

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: Actually there is no html. Project is using Extjs code and on top applying  css to modify the existing styles

Comment: You are overlooking the fact that the HTML generated by ExtJS may override your styles. Can you make a sencha fiddle exhibiting your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [`inputItemWidth`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging-cfg-inputItemWidth) config of [`pagingtoolbar`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging) to set the width of input box.

> `inputItemWidth` in pixels of the input field used to display and change the current page number.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g79)**, I have created a demo using `inputItemWidth` inside of `pagingtoolbar`. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        // create the Data Store
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

            pageSize: 50,

            autoLoad:true,

            fields: [
                'title', {
                    name: 'replycount',
                    type: 'int'
                }
            ],

            proxy: {
                // load using script tags for cross domain, if the data in on the same domain as
                // this page, an HttpProxy would be better
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: '//www.sencha.com/forum/topics-browse-remote.php',
                reader: {
                    root: 'topics',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                }
            }
        });



        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

            height: window.innerHeight,

            title: 'Demo',

            store: store,

            loadMask: true,

            // grid columns
            columns: [{
                text: "Topic",
                dataIndex: 'title',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: false
            }, {
                text: "Replies",
                dataIndex: 'replycount',
                width: 70,
                align: 'right',
                sortable: true
            }],

            // paging bar on the bottom
            bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
                emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
                inputItemWidth: 60
            }),

            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```